# notifyDataSetChanged не обновляет Адаптер

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть главный Фрагмент и диалоговое окно. И при клике на ОК на диалоговом окне ListView на главном фрагменте должен отфильтроваться.

Код который выполняеться при клике:

```
if (response != null && !response.equals("null\n")) {

                    MainFragment.filterPage++;

                    try {
                        JSONArray object = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < object.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject finalObject = object.getJSONObject(i);
                            VacancyModel model = new VacancyModel();

                            model.setId(Integer.parseInt(finalObject.getString(JSONKeyNames.ATTRIBUTE_ID)));
                            model.setHeader(finalObject.getString(JSONKeyNames.ATTRIBUTE_HEADER));
                            model.setProfession(finalObject.getString(JSONKeyNames.ATTRIBUTE_PROFESSION));

                            vacancyModelList.add(model);
                        }

                        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                MainVacancyAdapter adapter = new MainVacancyAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.main_row_layout, vacancyModelList);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Загрузились вакансии по фильтру!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Все правильно работает, отправляется и адаптер получает новые данные. Только список не обновляет

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А где привязка адаптера к listview?

Comment: Привязка в Главном Фрагменте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы создаете новый объект адаптера и от него вызываете `.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Либо устанавливайте этот новый адаптер для Вашего `ListView`, либо вызывайте `.notifyDataSetChanged()` для адаптера, который уже установлен.

Comment: ListView объявил статичным и установил MainFragment.listView.setAdapter(adapter); Заработало, спасибо!